# Mouse Click event not working

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

Hello Everyone I am doing a program for class and I can't get a mouse click event to work I got a key press event to work but for some reason I can't get the mouse click to even respond. I added the code and was wondering if anyone knew what I was doing wrong I prefer for it to work when I click on the text Calculate since I have to add a clear button after the Calculate. Thank you everyone who helps me figure this out.

P.S I use intelli J as my IDE I don't know if that was important or not

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class DecimalToBase extends Application {
protected TextField tfDecimal = new TextField();
protected TextField tfOctal = new TextField();
protected TextField tfBinary = new TextField();
protected Button tfCalculate = new Button();

@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Set text field preferences
    tfDecimal.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfOctal.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfBinary.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfCalculate.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);

    // Create a grid pane and add nodes to it
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setHgap(10);
    pane.setVgap(2);
    pane.add(new Label("Decimal"), 0, 0);
    pane.add(tfDecimal, 1, 0);
    pane.add(new Label("Octal"), 0, 1);
    pane.add(tfOctal, 1, 1);
    pane.add(new Label("Binary"), 0, 2);
    pane.add(tfBinary, 1, 2);
    pane.add(new Label("Calculate"),0,3);


    // Create and register handlers
    tfDecimal.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            tfOctal.setText(Integer.toOctalString(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText())));

            tfBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText())));
        }
    });

    tfOctal.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            tfDecimal.setText(String.valueOf(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfOctal.getText(), 10)));

            tfBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfOctal.getText(), 10)));
        }
    });

    tfBinary.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            tfDecimal.setText(String.valueOf(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfBinary.getText(), 2)));

            tfOctal.setText(Integer.toOctalString(
                    Integer.parseInt(tfBinary.getText(), 2)));
        }
    });
    tfCalculate.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    tfDecimal.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText())));

                    tfOctal.setText(Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText())));

                    tfBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText())));
                }
            });
    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Program16-Base Converter"); // Set the stage 
title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}
}
```

Comment: `tfCalculate` doesn't seem to be added to the scene

Comment: You should also consider using `setOnAction` handler (as demonstrated in [Using JavaFX UI Controls, Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm)) as there is typically more then one way a button might be triggered

Comment: Oh thanks that seemed to be it I can't believe I missed that thank you @MadProgrammer

Comment: You can either self-answer - or the question will be closed as "simple typographical error"

Comment: Update I got the calculate button to work but it it only works when I put a number in the decimal spot and not the other 2 if anyone knows why this is happening you input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As well as using an `onAction` handler on the button, you should also not be using key handlers on the text field - they won't be triggered if the user copies and pastes text using the mouse, for example. Instead, register a listener with the text fields' `textProperty()`.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` will fail (throw an exception) if the text is empty or not a valid integer value